# What is the famous phrase?

Tags: wordplay, english, word-property

The following words have synonyms that build a famous phrase:

> along huge skill appear big duty

What is the famous phrase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase is :

> With great power comes great responsibility

Comment: uncle ben was a wise man

Comment: I guess this was harder to make than to answer :)